# Extension is blocked by the administrator. Could not load manifest

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to do something weird here.

I made an extension which works fine but I am trying to prevent the user removing it. It works preventing the removal with extensions from the store but not with mine, which gets removed after I add it in the regedit and if I try to add it again I get that error in the title.

The way I prevent from removing the extension is the following:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist
```

I add a string, and paste the extension id inside. After I do this, restart chrome, my extension gets removed, while a regular extension just gets it remove button removed.

I gave all possible persmissions to the folder containing the extension, I don't know what to do more, this being first chrome extension I ever done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Chrome won't let you to prevent uninstalling a "load unpacked" extension by ExtensionInstallForcelist.
It only allows those extensions which are installed by their .crx file along with a private key (ID).

So, to prevent uninstallation of your self made extension, at first you need to

- Pack the extension by visiting "**chrome://extensions/**" in your chrome browser. After turning on developer mode, click on "**Pack Extension**" and then select the folder which contains your extension by clicking on "Browse" of Extension Root Directory. For Private Key file, leave it blank as it is.
- After that, **a .crx file will be created**. Now, drag the .crx file and release it on "chrome://extensions/" page, it'll be added to chrome along with an unique ID.
- Lastly, copy that ID and go to "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist", add a string, and paste the extension id in "Value data" field, followed by "**[;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx](https://;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx)**" (without spaces). Set "Value name" to be 1.
- Restart chrome, and you'll see that your extension can't be removed.